# mySQL CASE giving Err 1064

Tags: mysql, case, mysql-error-1064

I've dug around for this answer. I have two identical tables, contacts and contacts_copy. Each has fullname, Company, street, city, state and zip. If contacts.street is not NULL, then I select those items. If it is, I select those items from the duplicate table.

```
SELECT contacts.fullname,
CASE WHEN contacts.street IS NULL
THEN
contacts_copy.Company,
contacts_copy.street,
contacts_copy.city,
contacts_copy.state,
contacts_copy.zip
ELSE
contacts.Company,
contacts.street,
contacts.city,
contacts.state,
contacts.zip
END CASE
FROM contacts_copy, contacts
WHERE contacts.Company = contacts_copy.fullname
AND contacts.kind = 'Person'
ORDER BY contacts.last DESC



I keep getting:
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
contacts_copy.street,
contacts_copy.city,
contacts_copy.state,
contacts_cop' at line 4
```

There must be an easier way to do this. MySQL error messages are quite unhelpful.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this with MySQL, or any kind of SQL I've seen. The columns you're selecting must be specific, but the values can be conditional.

What you can do is have an `IF()` clause for each column in your results:

```
SELECT contacts.fullname,
  IF(contacts.street IS NULL, contacts_copy.Company, contacts.Company),
  ...
```

That should have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** table aliases have been changed, and extra `company.kind` clause added.

One approach is to use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT person.last,
       person.fullname,
       person.Company,
       person.street,
       person.city,
       person.state,
       person.zip
  FROM contacts person
  WHERE person.kind = 'Person'
    AND person.street IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT person.last,
       person.fullname,
       company.Company,
       company.street,
       company.city,
       company.state,
       company.zip
  FROM contacts person
  INNER JOIN contacts company ON person.Company = company.fullname
  WHERE company.kind = 'Company'
    AND person.kind = 'Person'
    AND person.street IS NULL
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Unfortunately this does require you to include the sort column in the results.

Note for the eagle-eyed: unlike the original attempt, this version will include rows from `person` where `street` is not `NULL` although no matching `company` entry exists.

Comment: Neil, this is almost it. Here's an image of my original table to give you an idea. I need to populate the street, city, state and zip for records where kind = person with the data from matching company. http://versastudio.com/misc/contactsTbl.png If I can match these two records, for example, I can get the data filled in. Thanks!

Comment: @4midori I've edited my answer slightly to make it align more with your image, but if that doesn't help, then you need to make it more clear where my answer doesn't match your expectation.

Comment: The data is an export of contacts from a CRM. The problem with the data they give me is that contacts of kind = people do not include the associated company street/city/state/zip.  So in the example, since Luke Brindley is of kind = person, and his Company field has a matching Company entry, the street/city/state/zip of his Company should be filled in for him, in other words, records of kind = Company should populate records of type = person.

fullname       Company       street        city    state    zip
Luke Brindley  Jammin' J...  227 Maple...  Vienna  VA       22180

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c1.fullname AS fullname,  
c1.Company AS company,  
c1.first AS firstname,  
c1.last AS lastname,  
c2.street AS street,  
c2.city AS city,  
c2.state AS state,  
c2.zip AS zip   
FROM contacts AS c1, contacts AS c2 
WHERE c1.kind = 'Person'   
AND c1.Company = c2.fullname   
ORDER BY c1.last ASC;
```

Was the answer.